# Filter rows containing modules and software version values and retain unique modules with highest version

Tags: php, arrays, max, filtering, version

I have an array like this :

```
Array (
    [vendor] => Array (
        [0] => Array ( [name] => module-one [version] => 1.7.0 )
        [1] => Array ( [name] => module-one [version] => 1.8.0 )
        [2] => Array ( [name] => module-two [version] => 1.8.0 )
        [3] => Array ( [name] => module-two [version] => 1.2.0 )
        [4] => Array ( [name] => module-three [version] => 1.9.0 )
        [5] => Array ( [name] => module-three [version] => 1.8.0 )
    )
)
```

I would like to compare the array by the key **name** and if it's a match get the highest version available like this :

```
Array (
    [vendor] => Array (
        [0] => Array ( [name] => module-one [version] => 1.8.0 )
        [1] => Array ( [name] => module-two [version] => 1.8.0 )
        [2] => Array ( [name] => module-three [version] => 1.9.0 )
    )
)
```

Comment: When you ask for help on Stack Overflow, please always include proof of research and your best coding attempt -- this helps to prevent DVs on your question.

Comment: What have you done to achieve the goal, and which are your errors and problems that you have with your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a [native version comparison function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) that makes this job very simple.  Group by the `name` values and when you encounter any subsequent rows that match a particular group -- only save the new row if the version is greater.

I've altered your sample input to indicate that multi-digit version values will be treated correctly.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3BTLv))

```
$vendor = [
    [ "name" => "module-one", "version" => "1.7.0" ],
    [ "name" => "module-one", "version" => "1.8.0" ],
    [ "name" => "module-two", "version" => "1.8.0" ],
    [ "name" => "module-two", "version" => "1.12.0" ],
    [ "name" => "module-three", "version" => "1.9.0" ],
    [ "name" => "module-three", "version" => "1.8.0" ],
];

$result = [];
foreach ($vendor as $row) {
    if (
        !isset($result[$row['name']])
        || version_compare($result[$row['name']]['version'], $row['version'], '<')
    ) {
        $result[$row['name']] = $row;
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'module-one',
    'version' => '1.8.0',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'module-two',
    'version' => '1.12.0',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'module-three',
    'version' => '1.9.0',
  ),
)
```

Comment: indeed, this is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
// assuming your array is called $rows

$latest_modules = [];

foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $name = $row['name'];
   $version = $row['version'];

   if (empty($latest_modules[$name]) || ($latest_modules[$name] < $version))  {
         $latest_modules[$name] = $version;
   }
}

print_r($latest_modules);
```

-- UPDATE

@nice_dev pointed out that the comparison won't work for all version cases.

Example, 1.12.1 vs 1.2.1 would return 1.2.1 as the bigger version which is incorrect.

```
 // assuming your array is called $rows

$latest_modules = [];

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $version = $row['version'];

    if (empty($latest_modules[$name])) {
        $latest_modules[$name] = $version;
    }
    else {
        $latest_modules[$name] = max_version($latest_modules[$name], $version);
    }
}

print_r($latest_modules);


function max_version($a, $b) {
    $a_parts = explode('.', $a);
    $b_parts = explode('.', $b);

    if (count($a_parts) !== count($b_parts)) {
        throw new \Exception('Both versions must be in same format major.minor.bugfix');
    }

    foreach ($a_parts as $key => $a_val) {
        $b_val = $b_parts[$key] ?? 0;

        if ($a_val > $b_val) {
            return $a;
        }
        elseif ($b_val > $a_val) {
            return $b;
        }
        // $a_val and $b_val are equal, continue through look at check next value.
    }

    // both values are the same, doesn't matter which one we return
    return $a;
}
```

Comment: Does string comparisons with versions work ok?

Comment: It does on the examples that were given, but if you end up with versions like 1.21.0, it won't

Comment: @mickmackusa Didn't know that PHP had a `version_compare()` builtin already.